# Does enabling Azure App Insight telemetry from ASP.NET MVC & C# code have any performance side effects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, appinsights, dynatrace, azure-application-insights-profiler

Does enabling Azure App Insight telemetry from C# code have any performance side effects?

1. I have referenced Azure App Insight NuGet package in my ASP.NET MVC project
2. After installing app insight NuGet package it automatically add few entries into `web.config` and `package.config` etc
3. In `App_start` and `begin_request` events of ASP.NET MVC, I have added code to log tenant id and userid in app insight (custom dimensions)
4. Checked-in my code and deployed to Azure Web app through CI\CD
5. I have enabled Dynatrace extension for Azure web app
6. In Dynatrace it shows that App insight telemetry is impacting performance of application

**Question**: is it possible that App Insight telemetry logging can affect performance of ASP.NET MVC app?

I un-installed App Insight telemetry logging and custom dimensions logging and as per Dynatrace, we found some performance gain

Comment: *In Dynatrace it shows that App insight telemetry is impacting performance of application* -> Can you explain how it shows you that?

Comment: AFAIK,there will be some performance issues but not much.It will be based on the amount of traces you are logging.

Comment: Refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?tabs=net#how-do-i-instrument-an-application).[Image](https://i.imgur.com/KraWtcf.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview?tabs=net#how-do-i-instrument-an-application),

> The instrumentation monitors your app and directs the telemetry data to an Application Insights resource by using a unique token. The effect on your app's performance is small.

- There will be some change in the performance, but the impact will be less on the App when we have Configured/Enabled Application Insights from code.
- Instead of tracking all the logs, try to reduce the traces by setting the appropriate logging configuration.
- We can use [sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#when-to-use-sampling) for the WebApp to have control on the traces to be logged.
- When we configure Application Insights from `Connected Services`, by default all the packages related to Application Insights will be Installed.

***`.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.2.4.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector, Version=2.15.0.44797, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.15.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector, Version=2.15.0.44797, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.15.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel, Version=2.15.0.44797, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.15.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.Web, Version=2.15.0.44798, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.15.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer, Version=2.15.0.44797, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.15.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.15.0.44797, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.15.0\lib\net46\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
   <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.1.0.8\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

- Check and try to remove the packages which you are not using.
- Removing the unnecessary packages will help in improving the performance.